# Deleting dynamic gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic-controls

I have a page that dynamically creates gridviews on button click which that works fine. And along with it creating a grid, on the top of the grid there is a linkbutton to delete it. Now, what i am trying to accomplish is that when i delete one of the grids it will delete the grid from the page and resync the numbers. Meaning, lets say i have the following:

```
Grid1
Grid2
Grid3
Grid4
```

If i decide to delete Grid3, what actually happens is this:

```
Grid1
Grid2
Grid4
```

And then if i click something on the page for it to reload or something, then it will resync the numbers correctly:

```
Grid1
Grid2
Grid3
```

I have no idea why its doing that and why it doesn't do it this way in the first place. Can someone please help me with this?

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ctrlname = this.Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");

        if (Session["Tables"] == null)
        {

            Session.Add("Tables", 1);

            DataTable dt = GetTable();

            Session.Add(Session["Tables"].ToString(), dt);
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.ID = "Grid-" + Session["Tables"].ToString();
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.ID = "Delete-Grid-" + Session["Tables"].ToString();
            lb.Text = "Delete Grid " + Session["Tables"].ToString();
            lb.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteGrid);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(gv);

        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            int next = (int)Session["Tables"];

            for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Session["Tables"]; i++)
            {
                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.ID = "Grid-" + i.ToString();
                gv.DataSource = (DataTable)Session[i];
                gv.DataBind();
                LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                lb.ID = "Delete-Grid-" + i.ToString();
                lb.Text = "Delete Grid " + i.ToString();
                lb.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteGrid);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(gv);
            }
            if (ctrlname == "Button1")
            {
                next = next + 1;
                Session["Tables"] = next;
                DataTable dt = GetTable();
                Session.Add(Session["Tables"].ToString(), dt);
                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.ID = "Grid-" + next.ToString();
                gv.DataSource = (DataTable)Session[next];
                gv.DataBind();
                LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                lb.ID = "Delete-Grid-" + next.ToString();
                lb.Text = "Delete Grid " + next.ToString();
                lb.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteGrid);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(gv);
            }

        }
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




    protected void DeleteGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton gridLink = (LinkButton)sender;
        String gridNum = gridLink.ID.ToString().Split('-').Last();

        GridView grid = (GridView)this.Page.FindControl("Grid-" + gridNum);
        LinkButton lbd = (LinkButton)this.Page.FindControl("Delete-Grid-" + gridNum);


        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(grid);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(lbd);

        int next = (int)Session["Tables"];
        next = next - 1;
        Session.Add("Tables", next);
        Session.Remove(gridNum);
    }






    public DataTable GetTable()
    {
        //
        // Here we create a DataTable with a few columns.
        //
        // Create Datatable to store all colums
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DurationType", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 2;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 3;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 4;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 5;
        dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        return dt;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the life cycle of an asp.net page first.
please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx) article...

in your case, the delete even is firing after page load event.
therefore the sync is happening before the row is deleted.
may be you need to put the sync code in another method and call it after deletion...

Comment: do you have an example on how i would need to do that?

Comment: Hi Brad, no unfortunately, but it not hard to test, just create a method, copy the code from the 'if post-back' block and call the method after deletion.

Comment: yeah, but the issue is, that there is no method that resyncs the numbers, it does it automatically, but it just doesn't do it right after i click delete